# How to create a Mathematica list of fewer columns from larger list of many columns

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list "data1":

`{{1, 6, 4.5, 1, 141.793, 2.31634, 27.907}, {2, 7, 4.5, 1, 133.702, 
  2.28725, 26.7442}, {3, 5, 5, 1, 136.546, 2.33522, 25.5814}, {4, 8, 
  5, 1, 104.694, 2.27871, 24.4186}}`

What I would like to do is to  create a new table with only the first two columns of each element. So my new table would be:

```
{{1,6},{2,7},{3,5},{4,8}}
```

I tried 
    `data1[[All, 1][All, 2]]`

and other variations but I am not understanding how to capture the desired fields. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have a range or list of the indices you want as the second argument, like so:

```
In[71]:= data[[All, {1, 2}]]
Out[71]= {{1, 6}, {2, 7}, {3, 5}, {4, 8}}
```

Comment: Perfect! I should of asked 2 hours ago.